# Qt Creator: New plain C project without compiling and using Qt

Tags: qt-creator

I want to use QT Creator simply as text editor (fascinating editor) and compile outside the IDE.
I downloaded free version of QT and try to create new project:

**New Project -> Non-Qt project -> Plain C Project (Creates a plain C project using qmake, not using the QT library) -> Choose... -> set URL ->**

And next Creator says "**No valid kits found**".

When I try to Add new kit in **Tools -> Options -> Build&Run -> QT Versions (currently empty) -> Add ->** I can not find any files named "qmake.exe" that he asks.

Which workaround I can use to resolve it? Where should I find qmake.exe file???

Answer (score 0):

You find it along with Qt libraries (bin/qmake)